# Flutter : How to edit bundle Identifier [ios] in windows

Tags: android, xcode, flutter

As some part of flutter code for ios needs to be edited in Xcode, is there a way to edit smaller things like bundle identifier of the app within the windows platform itself?

I need the bundle identification so I could use it to call it in firebase.the bundle identification are different for both ios and android hence the issue

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `project.pbxproj`, look for `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER`; there are multiple configurations, make sure to rename all of them properly.